# Running macros in a macro in excel

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that runs 2 other macros. However, the second macro requires you to select the location of the file where the data is. Is there a way of running the second macro 10 times for 10 different file locations. In summary, I would have 10 loops with both macros.

Some along the lines of the following sudo code:

```
file_loc = ('c:/users/desktop/....sim1.csv','c:/users/desktop/....sim2.csv'..'sim3'...sim10')

for i in range (10): 
    Run Macro1 
    wait for calculation 

    Run Macro2
    file = file_loc(i)
    wait for calculation 

    copy cell A10 (result) to AZ(i)
    next i
```

is this a possibility in VBA?

Comment: In VBA there is a decent debug mechanism. You should try by just hitting F5 and have a look. Btw, your `for` Loop needs an `Next i` at the end.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to link the second macro file location prompt with the file location in the code. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your macros look something like this:

```
Private Sub Macro1()
    ' Prompt for location
    ' Do stuff
End Sub
```

You could refactor this to:

```
Private Sub Macro1(Optional location As String = "")
    ' Test whether location was specified, and prompt for it if not
    ' Do stuff
End Sub
```

That way, you can loop through a list of locations and pass each one as a parameter, while still leaving the macro usable without this information.